# How to transition to a new controller when clicking on UICollectionViewCell (programatically)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have set up a ViewController with UICollectionViewCells, inside of a navigation controller. I want to be able to click on the cells and then have the user be taken to a new controller depending on which cell is selected (different controller for each cell). I want the navigation bar to still appear in the new controller, and have a back button that will take the user back to the original ViewController. I have the following code inside the initial view controller to set up the collection view cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: playlistCellId, for: indexPath) as! playlistCoverCell

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

I also register the cells correctly in viewDidLoad. What function do I use to perform an action when selecting a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let viewController = UIViewController() // or your custom view controller
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
         // and so on....
        }
}
```

> Tells the delegate that the item at the specified index path was
>   selected. The collection view calls this method when the user
>   successfully selects an item in the collection view. It does not call
>   this method when you programmatically set the selection.

Comment: what does indexPath.row represent? For example if I have two cells and I call this function and write this code: `if indexPath.row == 0` - Does this mean that the first cell was selected?

Comment: the first cell is at index 0. If you have 3 cells you will have index 0,1,2. indexPath.section represents the section (0 if you have just one)

Comment: That did not work for me. This is the code for my class: `class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` Is it OK that it is of type UIViewController, or does it have to be a UICollectionViewController? If this is not the issue, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. I used autocomplete to complete the function, and it left out `_ collectionView:` after the function declaration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try UICollectionViewDelegate in the function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY03B.png)

you can use indexPath to get elements of the current click;
push to next viewController you have to have navigationViewController, if navigationController is nil, you can try protocol or block. Sorry, my English is not good, maybe grammar is wrong.